# How to make document with 4 text columns

Tags: graphics, multicol, columns, text

i  tried to make document like it showed on the image below.My choice fell on `multicol` package(because it caught my eye first).

Here i faced into problems:

1. In the first place,enviroment `multicols` break text before text
   reaches the bottom of the page.But when i use this enviroment
   picture placed where it needed(through use `wrapfigure`) nonetheless
   without wrap.
2. In the second place,enviroment `multicols*` works fine for me,but
   every image placed on next page for no apparent reasons(as it looks
   for me).If i use `figure*` as it said in the documentation of the package, happens same thing.

So i want to make list with 4 columns, which contains pictures and equations.
[image]
My MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{multicols*}{4}
\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{h}{0.9\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{11.eps}
\end{wrapfigure}
{\tiny 
\blindtext[4]}
\end{multicols*}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

What it produces:[image]

Comment: Please reduce your code as much as possible. I do not have 11.eps or the package `pscyr`. You are loading `graphicx` twice. Please kick out everything not needed to show your issue here. This will be much easier for us.

Comment: Done.I left eps because it makes no difference(in other words,even if picture is not exist, document will havel wrap like it exist) and without it my example is meaningless.

Comment: @JHZTMEUIBNA you can replace `\includegraphics` by `\rule{1cm}{1cm}` or whatever size shows the problem to make an example people can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`multicols` doesn't support floats but you don't need floats for such a document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{multicols*}{4}
% pointless having wrapfig that is 90% of the width so uses ...........4
% wrapfig has no {h} so I used {r}
\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{l}{0.4\linewidth}
\tiny\let\normalsize\tiny\centering
    \rule{.9\linewidth}{1cm}
\caption{a wrap fig}
\end{wrapfigure}
{\tiny 
\blindtext[2]

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\tiny\let\normalsize\tiny\centering
 \rule{.9\linewidth}{1cm}
\captionof{figure}{another figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{l}{0.4\linewidth}
\tiny\let\normalsize\tiny\centering
    \rule{.9\linewidth}{1cm}
\caption{a wrap fig}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext[8]

}%NEED the blank line here
\end{multicols*}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: note I used `\tiny` here as you had done so but it is almost certainly better to use a normal size such as 10pt so that math fonts can scale correctly and then print to an over-sized paper say A2 and then shrink the pdf while printing.